# How can i remove the paragraph from shortcodes content?

Tags: shortcode

If you have created shortcodes in Wordpress, you may have noticed that when you get the content of your shortcode, it's wrapped in html paragraph tags.

I don't know why the progammers did that. It seems like a very bad idea to me to add formatting to the actual content.

I've found a post that presents this solution :

http://donalmacarthur.com/articles/cleaning-up-wordpress-shortcode-formatting/

But i'm wondering : Is there a solution proposed by the wordpress API itself, or something that i am missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcodes, since they are inserted in the editor, comply to editor rules. Hitting the return in editor will generate a paragraph tag, just like any other text. It's one of the TinyMCE features. To read more about TinyMCE check out [their forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/index.php) and especially [this thread](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3878)

Comment: ahh, so that is why it happens. thanx :)

Comment: also, here's a link to some plugin options allowing you to change the default tinyMCE behaviour / replace the editor: http://wpmu.org/why-you-hate-the-wordpress-text-editor/

Answer (score 1):

The link in you're question is now extinct, so I'm not sure of the solution it suggested, but here's [another solution](http://sww.co.nz/solution-to-wordpress-adding-br-and-p-tags-around-shortcodes/) for posterity:

Add the following to functions.php to run the formatting after shortcodes are evaluated:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

The author notes that you'll need to explicitly enable formatting within plugins that require it:

```
function my_shortcode($atts) {
    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
    [snip]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution which worked for me is to just remove paragraph end "</p>" from the beginning of the $content, and paragraph begin "<p>" from the end of the $content.

For example with regex like:

```
function fix_paragraphs($content)
{
    $patterns = array('/^<\/p>/i', '/<p>$/i');
    return preg_replace($patterns, '', $content);
}
```

Or if you're sure they'll be there, you could just trim them like this:

```
return substr($content, 4, -3);
```